# How do I find the duration in months, between a particular date and today's date, within SAS?

Tags: sas

I have created a table below;

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ start_date$;
CARDS;
John 20/09/1610.  
Michelle 26/09/1410.
Peter 10/03/1510. 
Kai 05/05/1710.   
run;
```

I then tried to find the duration in months, between the start_date and today's date, using the code below; But it did not work.

```
data test3;
set test3;
Duration_MONTHS = INTCK('MONTH', start_date, TODAY());
run;
```

Can someone help resolve the issue please?

Comment: you date seem odd and also you reading as a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your date as date things should work.

```
DATA test;
INPUT name$ start_date:ddmmyy10.;
format start_date ddmmyy10.;
CARDS;
John 20/09/1910
Michelle 26/09/1967
Peter 10/03/1997 
Kai 05/05/2004
 ; 
run;

data test3;
set test;
Duration_MONTHS = INTCK('MONTH', start_date, TODAY());
run;
```